# python argparse parameter order

Tags: python, parameters, argparse

Is there any way to manually order the parameters using the argparse module?

For now I have this:

```
usage: cons_test.py [-h] [-l L] [-R] [-O O] [-o O] [-T T] <STR_file> <PDB_file>
```

but I would like to have the positional (and so not optional) parameters before the optional parameters, like this:

```
usage: cons_test.py <STR_file> <PDB_file> [-h] [-l L] [-R] [-O O] [-o O] [-T T]
```

What should I modify on my code to achieve this order?

Comment: The simplest step, especially for a one off use, is to write your own `usage` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variation on Martijn Pieters solution - strip out all the line wrapping, and display the arguments in the order which they are defined.

```
class RawUsageHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _format_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix):
        # use actions in the order that they are define
        # no line wrapping
        if prefix is None:
            prefix = 'usage: '
        if usage is not None:
            usage = usage % dict(prog=self._prog)
        elif usage is None and not actions:
            usage = '%(prog)s' % dict(prog=self._prog)
        elif usage is None:
            prog = '%(prog)s' % dict(prog=self._prog)
            format = self._format_actions_usage
            action_usage = format(actions, groups)
            usage = ' '.join([s for s in [prog, action_usage] if s])
        return '%s%s\n\n' % (prefix, usage)
```

sample output:

```
usage: stack24221824.py [-h] <STR_file> [-t T] <PDB_file> [-l {txt,html,pdf}] [-R] [-O {txt,html,pdf}]
```

`[-h]` is first because the parser creates that right away.  Then I defined `STR`, `-t`, `PDB`, etc.  If needed I think you could suppress the help with `add_help=True`, and define your own `-h` argument later.  If you want line wrapping you have to worry about where it is allowed to split the line, and indenting for subsequent lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not without providing your own [formatter class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#formatter-class). Creating one that reverses the optional and positional arguments *can* be done with a subclass, but note that this relies on internal methods that *can* change between Python versions.

The following class will work in Python 2 and 3, as the overridden method is still called in the same way, but *only* for text fitting within the terminal width (using the `COLUMNS` environment variable, defaulting to 80 columns minus 2 characters padding):

```
class SwappedOrderHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _format_actions_usage(self, actions, groups):
        # split optionals from positionals
        optionals = []
        positionals = []
        for action in actions:
            if action.option_strings:
                optionals.append(action)
            else:
                positionals.append(action)
        return super(SwappedOrderHelpFormatter, self)._format_actions_usage(
            positionals + optionals, groups)
```

Tell `argparse` to use this when creating your argument parser:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    # ....
    formatter_class=SwappedOrderHelpFormatter,
    # ....
    )
```

If your text is not going to fit most terminal widths, then you need to re-define the [`argparse.HelpFormatter._format_usage()` method](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/argparse.py#l292) entirely, and swap the order of the `optionals` and `positionals` variables.

Demo:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', formatter_class=SwappedOrderHelpFormatter)
>>> parser.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['-l'], dest='l', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('-R')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-R'], dest='R', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('STR_file')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='STR_file', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('PDB_file')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='PDB_file', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: PROG STR_file PDB_file [-h] [-l] [-R R]

positional arguments:
  STR_file
  PDB_file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -l
  -R R
```

Comment: I believe you would have to make further changes to handle long multiline usage.

Comment: @hpaulj: ah, I see what you mean. `if len(prefix) + len(usage) > text_width:` then positionals are formatted separately from optionals.

Comment: That `_format_usage` method is fragile.  It gets a string back from `_format_actions_usage`, and tries to split it into `actions` and `group` units, and the splice them back into lines.  My patch in http://bugs.python.org/issue11874 is a rewrite of these methods.

Comment: @hpaulj: The whole `HelpFormatter` class is rather fragile, really.

Comment: In a separated script your code works, but as soon as I add a new argument, namely

 `parser.add_argument("-O", "--output_file_name", choices=["txt", "html"], default="txt|html", help="output file name")`

the order goes back to normal:

`usage: SwappedOrder.py [-h] [-l {bic,pf1}] [-R] [-O {txt,html}] STR_file PDB_file`

What makes some arguments work and some not? Am I missing am argument option?

Comment: If the `usage` is now long enough to wrap (or nearly so), it's hitting the problem I mentioned in the 1st comment.

Comment: @Daniel: you'll have to switch to replacing the `_format_usage()` method I linked to; copy that to the subclass (instead of `_format_actions_usage()`) and swap around the order of the actions being processed, as I stated.